# How to append/remove multiple objects instances to/from a list Python?

Tags: python, list

im trying to append and remove multiple objects instances from a list in Python. However, I couldn't find a short way to do it and had to use to for cycles ... is there any compact way to do it ?

Append to list:

```
# Create objects
specialAgent.append(Boid(1)) 
specialAgent.append(Boid(2)) 
for i in range(2):
    boids.append(specialAgent[-1-i])
```

Remove from list:

```
# Destroy objects
for i in range(len(specialAgent)):
    boids.remove(specialAgent[i])
```

Comment: Please note that removing in this way has a complexity of ``O(len(specialAgent) * len(boids))``, if the number of items are large you may need a better way to remove them, e.g. using another data structure.

Comment: well indeed sometimes the script goes quite slow, which structure would you recommend to store the object instances in ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use slice assignment:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> L[3:] = [4, 5, 6]
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> L[-3:] = []
>>> L
[1, 2, 3]
```

You can also append multiple items to a list using the `.extend()` list method:

```
>>> L.extend([4, 5, 6])
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```